# Replaced text in a Doc is missing in converted PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, export-to-pdf

I am starting in Google Apps Script and trying to create a copy of a file (Google Doc), then replace text in the copied document and convert it to PDF.

The function works fine, but the text replaced does not appear in the PDF file, but appears in the copied file (where I replaced).

I read about the `saveandclose()` method to save changes and close the document  (copied) before the function finishes to eject. But it seem that the method is not available. I really appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
function replaceconvert() {
  var cdoc = DriveApp.getFileById('iddocument').makeCopy('filename321');
  var iddoc = cdoc.getId();

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(iddoc);
  doc.getBody().replaceText('nombre', 'Juan Perez');

  var doc_repl = DriveApp.getFileById(iddoc);
  var blob = doc_repl.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

  DriveApp.getFolderById(idfolder).createFile(doc1)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "But it seem that the method is not available."? Did you get an error? If so, add the textual error message to the question.

Answer (score 5):

I do use the following function, which works for me:

```
function personaliseAttachment(keyTemplate, member, fileName){

  var cloneId = DriveApp.getFileById(keyTemplate).makeCopy('cloneAttachment').getId();
  var clone = DocumentApp.openById(cloneId);

  var body = clone.getBody();

  for (var property in member) {
    if (member.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      body.replaceText("{{"+property+"}}", member[property]);
    }
  }
  clone.saveAndClose();

  var clonePDF = DriveApp.createFile(clone.getAs('application/pdf'));
  clonePDF.setName(fileName);

  DriveApp.getFileById(cloneId).setTrashed(true);

  return clonePDF;
}
```